# Array operation

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have this string(It's example only):

```
$string='cat-cat.png-0,dog-dog.jpg-0,phone-nokia.png-1,horse-xyz.png-0';
```

And code to remake this string

```
$string=explode(",", $string);
$i = 0;
$ile=count($string);
while ($i < $ile) {
    $a = explode("-", $string[$i]);
    if($a[2]==0) $animal .= $a[0].' '.$a[1];
    elseif($a[2]==1) $thing .= $a[0].' '.$a[1];
    $i++;
}
```

I need to search this array and grouping in: $animal and $thing
I know why this code not working, but i haven't any idea to do this. Help me please :)

Comment: You should consider to use more self-explaining variable-names. This style of coding isn't making it any easier for yourself.

Comment: expected output is basic need to give you idea how to do this.

Comment: THX for interesting, I chose one solution from answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also achieve it by using `preg_match` in cases when your image name contain other characters like extra `-` or numbers, here is example:

```
$string = 'cat-cat.png-0,dog-snoopy-dog.jpg-0,phone-nokia-6310.png-1,rabbit-bugs-bunny-eating-carrot.png-0,ignore-me';

$tmp = explode(',', $string);

$animals = $things = array();

foreach($tmp as $value)
{
    preg_match('/(?P<name>[A-Za-z]+)-(?P<file>[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+)-(?P<number>\d+)/', $value, $matches);

    if($matches)
    {
        switch($matches['number'])
        {
            case '0':
                array_push($animals, sprintf('%s %s', $matches['name'], $matches['file']));
                break;
            case '1':
                array_push($things, sprintf('%s %s', $matches['name'], $matches['file']));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'cat cat.png' (length=11)
  1 => string 'dog snoopy-dog.jpg' (length=18)
  2 => string 'rabbit bugs-bunny-eating-carrot.png' (length=35)
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'phone nokia-6310.png' (length=20)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$string = 'cat-cat.png-0,dog-dog.jpg-0,phone-nokia.png-1,horse-xyz.png-0';
$array = explode(",", $string);
$list = array();

foreach ( $array as $info ) {
    list($prifix, $name, $id) = explode("-", $info);
    $list[$id][] = $prifix . "-" . $name;
}

var_dump($list);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'cat-cat.png' (length=11)
      1 => string 'dog-dog.jpg' (length=11)
      2 => string 'horse-xyz.png' (length=13)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'phone-nokia.png' (length=15)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish the task:

```
$string = 'cat-cat.png-0,dog-dog.jpg-0,phone-nokia.png-1,horse-xyz.png-0';
$array  = explode(',', $string);
$animal = array();
$thing  = array();
foreach ($array as $item)
{
    $a = explode('-', $item);
    if( $a[2] == 1 )
    {
        $thing[] = $a[0] . ' ' . $a[1];
    }
    else
    {
        $animal[] = $a[0] . ' ' . $a[1];
    }
}
```

Then from there you can implode those arrays if you need them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you gave an example of what the code should output, or the resulting array that you wish to achieve.

If you are absolutely stuck with the input string format then you could use regular expressions to make this a little more robust. Something like:

/([^,]*)-(\d+)/

would match the filename and the type, assuming that the type was always a digit.

So for example:

```
preg_match_all("/([^,]*)-(\d+)/", "cat-cat.png-0,dog-dog.jpg-0,phone-nokia.png-1,horse-xyz.png-0", $matches); var_dump($matches);
$items = array();
foreach ($matches[2] as $key=>$type) {
    if (empty($items[$type])) {
        $items[$type] = array();
    }
    $items[$type][] = $matches[1][$key];
}
var_dump($items);
```

Ideally you'd want to add some more error checking, such as checking that matches returned as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
// Remove all things and all numbers with preceding hyphens
$animal = trim(preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z\-\.]+\-1,?)|(\-\d+)/', '', $string), ',');
// gives 'cat-cat.png,dog-dog.jpg,horse-xyz.png'

// Remove all animals and all numbers with preceding hyphens
$thing = trim(preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z\-\.]+\-0,?)|(\-\d+)/', '', $string), ',');
// gives 'phone-nokia.png'
```